# Using a function to append a unique identifier to each sub-list within an outputted list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, web-scraping, append

I have a function I made it to scrape table data from a long list of URLs (baseball statistics). Each URL input contains a unique table for a single player, with multiple rows of data. The rows on each URL represent all of the seasons in a player's career. The input parameter is, of course, a list of all URLs that I am scraping.

So the overall list of lists of lists contains statistical data of several players. For each player, we have multiple rows representing all of the years of their career.

All of the URLs are from the same domain, but with different extensions.  Example list:

```
input_list = ['www.baseball.com/BarryBonds01', 'www.baseball.com/JohnRSmith01', 'www.baseballl.com/MickyJMantle01', 'www.baseball.com/JohnJSmith02, www.baseball.com/MickySMantle02]
```

However, the tables on each URL page do not contain a unique identifier. So when I create the final list of lists of lists and the final dataframe, I have a long list of columns with all of my data but nothing that uniquely identifies each sub-list within the overall dataframe.

How can I append a unique identifier for each sub-list (for each player)? An ideal identifier would be the URL extension, but I can't figure out the code to make this happen.

Currently, my output list of lists of lists looks something like this (each list of lists within the broader list of lists of lists is a single player):

```
output_list = [[[45, 54, 23, 23], [44, 22, 11, 55]], # Player A
               [[32, 23, 54, 23], [223, 44, 55, 66], [23, 67, 74, 24]], # Player B
               [[32, 46, 77, 44], [24, 65, 24, 44]], # Player C
               [[23, 2, 5, 7], [22, 455, 44, 332]], # Player D
               [[33, 33, 22, 55], [88, 2, 4, 66], [1, 0, 0, 8], [3, 3, 5, 6]]] # Player E
```

The output figure, however, looks like this -- with no identification of the row data belonging to particular players.

[image: dataframe image baseball data]

Here is a better representation of my output list:

```
output_list = [[45, 54, 23, 23], [44, 22, 11, 55], # Player A
                   [32, 23, 54, 23], [223, 44, 55, 66], [23, 67, 74, 24], # Player B
                   [32, 46, 77, 44], [24, 65, 24, 44], # Player C
                   [23, 2, 5, 7], [22, 455, 44, 332], # Player D
                   [33, 33, 22, 55], [88, 2, 4, 66], [1, 0, 0, 8], [3, 3, 5, 6]] # Player E
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a dictionary that stores the URLs as the key (or at least the unique extension of the base URL), and the data as a value. Without more info, it's not really possible to answer this.

Comment: I added clarifying information to hopefully make my question easier to understand. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide an example of what your desired output would look like.

Comment: I edited `output_list` to be a little clearer about the structure I think you're saying it has.  Can you confirm the `# Player` comments on each line are correct?  Also, are you saying you want both row-labels for player name and column-labels for URL source?  Providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be of help here.

Comment: Yeah, your #Player comments are correct. I couldn't think of a good way to convey that.

I only need each #Player list to have a unique identifier on each row. I already have column headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a very robust method to achieve what you want, but without more details it is difficult to advice. In a crunch, this should work:

```
# Since input and output are same length and aligned
# We enumerate output to get the position, and value
# Then use the position to find the corresponding element in input
# Slice an identifier corresponding input
# Append to all relevant output

for index, player in enumerate(output_list):

    # Slice URL from '/' onwards
    identifier = input_list[index][input_list[index].find('/'):]


    # loop through all players for stats
    for stats in player:

        # append identifier for each list of stat
        stats.append(identifier)
```

This should give you an additional column with the identifier when you convert the list of list of list to a df.

There are better ways to accomplish this, like `.zip()` or `pd.DataFrame.from_dict()`, but this should fit right into your code without much changes downstream.

---

I will leave the original answer for future reference for other users.

With regards to your new output format, there is no possible way to format it after scraping. The 'easiest' way is to add the identifier using the above method, *during* scraping.

For example:

```
master_list = []

for URL in input_list:

    identifier = get_identifier(URL)
    temp_list = run_scrape(URL)

    for stats in temp_list
        stats.append(identifier)

    master_list = master_list + temp_list
```

I cannot give you concrete code since I don't know how you are doing it. All the functions you need can be derived from above samples, or can just be as is.

The general idea is to add the identifier every time you get a new set of data corresponding to your URL, before adding the 'identified-data' to a master_list, then go to the next URL.

Depending on how you are doing the scraping, you may or may not have control over the iteration process.

- If you do, the above should work
- If you don't, please check the docs for your library (there should be some method that allows for such insertion)

  - If the method does not exist, you can check the docs for smaller functions that give you more control (though your code will be more complex)
  - You can check S/O to see if anyone has a similar problem with the library you are using, and how they are solving it. Otherwise, you can ask a question specific to your library.

**This is not a pandas problem anymore**

Comment: I tried your method but I'm getting "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'." This is the same error I was getting when I tried a similar method previously. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I just copied the code and it works. Can you try it independently? i.e. run the code with only input, output, and above code, *without* any before / after code that you might have.

Comment: See my edit above, at the end of my post. Yes, your code works with my output_list as I wrote it above. The problem (my mistake) is that when I wrote my output_list sample, I was trying to convey that each list within double brackets represents a different player. But this is not actually what my output_list looks like -- there are no double brackets for each player. So it's just a list of lists, where each list is a row.  And I'm hoping to create a column containing an identifying label with a player's name that corresponds to each of the rows that belong to that player.

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope it helps

Comment: In your revised code, I'm not sure what this line is supposed to be: "temp_list = run_scrape(URL)"  ?

Comment: run_scrape(URL) is a pseudo code function that returns the contents of the URL in a list of list, given the URL.